# System.exit(0) гарантирует завершение всех потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

System.exit(0) гарантирует завершение всех потоков? В GUI программе использую множество Thread-ов, если выйти с программы с помощью System.exit(0), завершатся ли все потоки в программе?

Comment: System,exit(0) завершает java-процесс в рамках которого живут потоки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации System.exit(n) останавливает JVM:

> [Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int))

Поэтому все потоки запущенные в этом экземпляре JVM завершаются.